# XPath - How to run CONCAT for each result separately?

Tags: xpath

I am using XPATH 1.0 and have some XML that looks like this:

```
<item>
    <images>
        <image value="/img/someimage1.png">some title1</image>
        <image value="/img/someimage2.png">some title2</image>
        <image value="/img/someimage3.png">some title3</image>
        <image value="/img/someimage4.png">some title4</image>
    </images>
</item>
```

The problem is, I need to concat the base url and the @value of these images to get the full downloadable URL. For example in the context of //item:

```
concat("http://someurl.com", /images/image/@value)
```

This kind of works, however, it only returns the first image. Not all four (an array). Is there a way to do something along the lines of this?

```
/images/image/concat("http://someurl.com", @value)
```

In other xpath versions I think string-join would work? Not sure about that though, because we are using concat. Either way, is this possible in xpath 1?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `/images/image/concat("http://someurl.com", @value)` is XPath 2.0. With pure XPath 1.0 you can't construct the same, you would need to iterate in your host language over the `images/image` element and then use XPath 1.0 on each image to compute `concat("http://someurl.com", @value)` and then in the host language you would need to build an array of strings or concatenate them as needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Kind of what I expected. I think I have an idea, so it will be fine.